# Will acquiring a second language improves the person's general intelligence and reading?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, cognitive, cognitive-enhancement

According to this information will acquiring a second language improves the person's general intelligence and reading, even if the individual started learning and have learned it after the age of 18?

How scienctifically and/or empirically accurate is the studies and information?

https://www.bbc.com/news/health-27634990

https://youtu.be/RXeDNkVauh4